Opening .img file created in Erdas Imagine 2023 in Erdas Imagine 2022
I am having an issue working with a file created in Erdas Imagine 2023 in Erdas Imagine 2022. I ran a tool with the output .img. However, the .img format seems to be different in Erdas 2023 vs Erdas 2022 and therefore I am unable to use the file in 2022. Is there any way to make this file compatible with Erdas 2022?

From 2023 Release Notes: "IMAGINE Image File format (IMG)
The IMAGINE Image File Format (IMG) has been extended to provide support for lossless compressed IMG
files larger than 2GB (rather than using an uncompressed .ige external file), as well as the ability to persist a
NoData mask within the IMG file (rather than using a value).
However, these new capabilities may not be supported by other software applications yet, so the option to
store using the older External formatting is provided via a Preference."
